# vtigercrm installation issue

Tags: php, apache, vtiger

I have already installed **php5**, **php5-curl**, **php5-mysqli** by `sudo apt-get install` command. and have php version `PHP 5.5.23`.

But at the time of `vtigercrm` installation present PHP value show `No`.

PHP Configuration 
[image: Result of phpinfo();]
[image: Result when configure vtigercrm]
This did not resolve the issue - any help appreciated.

Comment: Can you redo the markup so the output is actually readable?

Comment: Saex Thanks. Only single issue is not fixing that - in step of Vtigercrm installation . Installation prerequisites in PHP Configuration , showing  PHP Present Value - NO.

Comment: thanks for views..  its done now.  I did change php version value 5.5 to 5.6  in module/model/install/Utils.php file . and its worked for me. Not any error now in installation...

Comment: You have given wrong path so adding new comment. \modules\Install\models\Utils.php

Answer (score 1):

> Change PHP version value 5.5 to 5.6 in module/model/install/Utils.php file . and its worked for me.